# Binary Search Tree inorder predecessor space complexity

Tags: binary-search-tree, computer-science

I am studying binary search trees and have not been able to find much information on the space required to find the predecessor of a given node.  Bases on an iterative approach, I believe I would need O(1) space (in-place) because we only need one variable plus a single node on a stack.  To accomplish this recursively, we would have to maintain a stack.  Since it is possible to traverse to the left most/minimum node, it is possible that we would traverse the entire height of the binary search tree.  Therefore, the space complexity for this would be O(h).

Are these assumptions correct or am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that each recursive call decreases the height, and there is only a single call for each height value. Therefore, we can perform an iterartive search.

Let `n1, n2` be nodes such that `n2` is the root and `n1` is null. 
Let `v` be the node you are looking for

While n2 is not `v`:

- `n1` := `n2`
- if `v.value` > `n2.value`, `n2` := `n2.right`
- else `n2` := `n.left`

return `n1`

I've kept a constant number (2) of pointers, therefore the complexity is `O(1)`.